# Firebase not working with google play services version 3265130

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

when i am adding intent and intent filter in menifest for firebase , it gives an error like 
Error:Execution failed for task ':ProjectName:processDebugResources'. > Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'

please get me help to resolve it.

Comment: Can we see your manifest? It'll be easier for us to pin point the issue...

Answer (score 0):

firebase is a esay way to integration in android.because firebase has send a configured file send Like google-service.json and all permission.

You can use google-service.json file in own project according to firebase console.

You can read all instruction  to given firebase developer console.